# Javascript array of objects: If objects have duplicate region value, return the object that has a status of "issued"

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with regions and status keys. If there are duplicate regions  and one of those duplicate regions has a status of "issued" I want to return that object with the status of "issued" and remove the other duplicates.

```
const arr = [
  {region: 'US', status: 'pending'},
  {region: 'US', status: 'restart'},
  {region: 'US', status: 'issued'},
  {region: 'FR', status: 'pending'},
  {region: 'FR', status: 'issued'},
  {region: 'MX', status: 'pending'},
  {region: 'MX', status: 'restart'},
  {region: 'KY', status: 'loading'},

];
```

My goal is to return the following...

```
const arr = [
  {region: 'US', status: 'issued'},
  {region: 'FR', status: 'issued'},
  {region: 'MX', status: 'pending'},
  {region: 'MX', status: 'restart'},
  {region: 'KY', status: 'loading'},
];
```

Comment: can you share what you've tried by yourself?

Comment: there is a rule of help here, it assumes that you have tried to solve your problem, so that we can help you to solve it. So where is your code? don't tell us that you didn't do anything and expect to get some code for free...

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks I will keep that in mind next time. I did try to solve my problem and was just returning the objects with "issued" and not the rest of the objects. Next time I'll post my attempts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest two passes: one to identify those entries that are issued, and one to make the removals based on that information:

```js
const arr = [{region: 'US', status: 'pending'},{region: 'US', status: 'restart'},{region: 'US', status: 'issued'},{region: 'FR', status: 'pending'},{region: 'FR', status: 'issued'},{region: 'MX', status: 'pending'},{region: 'MX', status: 'restart'},{region: 'KY', status: 'loading'},];

// First pass
const issued = new Set(arr.map(o => o.status === 'issued' && o.region));
// Second pass
const result = arr.filter(o => !issued.has(o.region) || o.status === 'issued');

console.log(result);
```

NB: the set `issued` will also collect a `false` value, but that will never match with a string, so I just didn't bother to remove it.